# MarkLogic server side API, Javascript, cts.search, search only in specific nodes

Tags: marklogic

In Marklogic XQuery server side API there is a possibility to run `cts.search` method in the following manner:

```
  cts:search(//SPEECH,
    cts:word-query("with flowers"))

  => ... a sequence of 'SPEECH' element ancestors (or self)
     of any node containing the phrase 'with flowers'.
```

My question is, is it possible to achieve such a result using Javascript API? Namely, to be able to run word-query only on the specific root-level nodes (as the database hosts a couple of different document types).

(As the nodes I mentioned will be root nodes, using `elementwordquery` does not seem a handy way to achieve the goal).

Comment: To clarify, you want to find documents that have one of a few specific root notes, and you want those root nodes to have a direct text() child that matches a word-query. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the JavaScript version of [`cts.search`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts.search) there is no expression parameter as with the [XQuery API](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:search). To search for words within a specific element and its text descendants, you can use a [`cts.elementWordQuery`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts.elementWordQuery). For example,

```
var resultsIterator = cts.search(cts.elementWordQuery(xs.QName('SPEECH'), 'with flowers'));
for(var doc of resultsIterator) {
  // …
}
```

This iterates through each of the documents. To get to contained `SPEECH` element, you could use [`doc.xpath('//SPEECH')`](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/jsref/api#id_32220) in the `for…of` loop.

Rather than relying solely on the root element as the document type identifier, I’d recommend using collections to manage groups of similarly typed documents. This is especially true if you’re managing JSON documents, which typically don’t have the notion of “root element”.

```
var resultsIterator = cts.search(cts.andQuery([
  cts.collectionQuery('Speeches'),
  cts.wordQuery('with flowers')
]));
for(var doc of resultsIterator) {
  // …
}
```